# Proof that this inequality is true for all real numbers a and b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \geq \sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}$ for all real $a,b$.
I tried with polar coordinates such that:
$\sqrt{r^2\sin^2\theta+r^2\cos^2\theta}\geq\sqrt[3]{r^3\sin^3\theta+r^3\cos^3\theta}$
And from here it sort of solves itself, but I'd like to see how to do it without polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Raise it to 6 power:

$$(a^2+b^2)^3\geq (a^3+b^3)^2$$

then we have to prove $$3a^4b^2+3a^2b^4\geq 2a^3b^3$$

So we have to prove $$3a^2+3b^2 \geq  2ab$$ which is true since $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$

Comment: As the problem is for 'all real $a$, $b$', strictly speaking we should first reduce the problem to positive $a$, $b$. (Which is trivial, but thought I'd mention it for completeness.)

Answer (score 2):

This method has the advantage of having to compute less variables.

Divide by $a$

$$
(1+(b/a)^2)^{1/2} \geq (1+(b/a)^3)^{1/3}
$$

Define $t=b/a$. Power 6 both sides will eventually give

$$
(1-t^2)^3 \geq (1+t^3)^2\\
t^2(3t^2-2t+3) \geq 0
$$

Now $t^2 \geq 0$, and you can check the discriminant of the quadratic equation is less than 0.